# am i able to use logical conditions in the javascript switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I'm in the middle of creating an online calculator, in which the user has the option of either inputting a number through a click event (by clicking a `button` element) or through the `keyboard` event. 
As of now I have two different `switch` statements - one for each each event. I was wondering if I can add a logical OR condition in the `switch` statement therefore only needing one of them?

Comment: please add the code.

Comment: Add an example of what you are trying to do please. Its tough to answer a question without any context

Answer (score 0):

A logical OR can by achieved by:

```js
function Switch(event) {
  let output = "Code to be executed if it's ";
  switch(event) {
    case 'click':
    case 'keyboard':
      console.log(output + "a 'click' or 'keyboard'");
      break;
    case 'other':
      console.log(output + "a 'other'");
      break;
    // default if non event is given
    default:
      console.log(output + "not 'other', 'click' or 'keyboard'");
      break;
  }
}

Switch("click");
Switch("keyboard");
Switch("other");
Switch();
```

Comment: Cant you use `default: //do something; break;` instead of using `'other'`?

Comment: @MasterYoda I added it to the snippet if he accept it.

Comment: @RensvWalstijn default will catch all other events that are not 'click' or 'keyboard' there is no need to include 'other' as a condition.

Comment: @MasterYoda 'other' is just an example of event. it's just an example

Comment: @Faly fair enough, sorry its Friday :)